# How can I delete field dependencies (controlling values) through destructive changes?

Tags: destructivechanges.xml, field-dependencies

Is there a way to delete just the  from my organization for specific fields through destructive changes?

I know this can be acomplished through git, but afaik it will not actually remove the dependencies, just remove them from the metadata.

Comment: Are you referring to delete the fields or the values? And when you say field dependencies, is it a picklist field dependency? Can you clarify a bit?

Comment: I want to keep both the fields and the picklist values. It is a picklist field dependency.

I have two picklist field Type__c and Sub_Type__c and the values from the latter depend on the values from the first.

I want to just delete the picklist values dependancies

Comment: You cannot delete picklist dependencies using metadata. Refer to the last comment on this [**question**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/193445/dependent-picklist-configuration-not-deploying) which provides some test results to confirm this.

Answer (score -2):

You can delete the dependency by Navigating to the Controlling Field and Navigate to the "Field Dependencies" Section and Delete the Required dependency

Comment: This is what you would do if you were using the web UI. OP is using the metadata API though, so this does not apply.